# "initializer element is not a compile-time constant" when assigning results of basic math operation in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, initialization

```
int x = 10;
float y= 3.5;
float z =x*y;
```

I enter this but i get an error where Xcode doesn't recognize the   *   and says
"initializer element is not a compile-time constant" 
What's happening?
(I am a complete beginner btw.)

Comment: " Xcode doesn't recognize the *" -- What gives you that impression? That's not what the error message says. "initializer element is not a compile-time constant" -- That's true, is it not? `x` and `y` are variables, non compile-time constants, so `x*y` is also not a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're declaring these at file scope. Global variables have to be initialised at compile time, not runtime, and you aren't allowed to initialise them with other variables.

If you declare these in a function there will be no problem. But if you're just using constants anyway, you can initialise `z` directly with 35.0.

Comment: This seems more likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign expression when you declare the z.
Try this

```
int x = 10;
float y= 3.5;
float z;
z=x*y;
```

Comment: Do you know why it is like that? It seems like a strange language feature.

Comment: @Jake223: That's an old C thing.  Used to be, you had to declare variables at the top of a block, before you did anything.  And math counts as something.  I thought that was relaxed considerably with C99, but eh.  Maybe Objective-C still uses the C89 rules.

Comment: @darkstar8500: Neither.  The point of the answer is, you declare the variables and then do your math after they're all declared.

Comment: "still not working" -- That's not a compiler error message. Be precise. Are these declarations in a function or at file scope? If the latter, you can't do this, of course.

Comment: @cHao - this doesn't count as mixed code and declarations as the variables are all being defined -- expressions in an initialisation are completely fine in C89 and Objective C, as long as the variables are not global/static.

Comment: @yibuyiqu If the OP gets this message, x, y and z are probably global variables, so this code might not apply.